# post value from one iframe to another iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have two iFrames in my page and I would like to the value of an input field form one iFrame to an input field of the other iFrame. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set a hidden field or something in the parent:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById(Client ID of Hidden Field).value = Selected IDs;
```

You will then need to set the src attribute of the second iFrame and append the value as part of the querystring

something like:

```
<iframe id='iFrame2' src='/myPage.html?val=myValue' ></iFrame>
```

You can probably do this in javascript, when I did I did it with asp.net as the scenario was different but probably something like:

```
$('#iFrame2').attr('src', '/myPage.html?val=' + $('#myHiddenField').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the easiest.  Can we assume that both the IFRAMES, and the parent document are all part of the same domain, and all the same doctype?  If not, security restrictions are likely to block you.

Also, what browser(s) do yo uneed it to work in?

Comment: yes they are, and for now i just want it to work in internet explorer. Maybe in the future i'd like it to work in all the browsers but that is not important wright now

Answer (score 0):

OK, given your answer above about being in the same domain, etc.

The answer about setting the URL of the IFRAME will work if you want to send/receive from the other IFRAME.  However, I read it as you want to set a value in an existing field.

If that is the case, you need to do something like:
1.  Assume IFRAMEs have the ids I1 and I2
2.  Put this code on the parent page (you can trigger / place it in a child, but it gets more complicated as you need to handle load/ready state and do additional lookups.

```
var if1 = document.getElementbyId('I1');
var if2 = document.getElementbyId('I2');
//Or use $get from AJAX framework, etc

var doc1 = if1.document;
var doc2 = if2.document;
//These may throw security or load exceptions if the IFRAMES are not loaded, cross domain, or do not contain HTML.

doc2.getElementById('targetElement').value = doc1.getElementById('sourceElement').value;
```

//You should do the usual checking for the element existing, etc